# Whmcs got a site error

Tags: php, wamp, whmcs

I bought WHMCS, and if I try to install it on my WAMP server "On a dedicated", server I got this error:

Site error: the file C:\wamp\www\whmcs\index.php requires the ionCube PHP Loader ioncube_loader_win_5.5.dll to be installed by the website operator. If you are the website operator please use the ionCube Loader Wizard to assist with installation.

And if I try to download the loader ioncube_loader_win_5.5.dll, my site get this error:

This webpage is not available

WHMCS dosen't support PHP 5.5, read [here](http://docs.whmcs.com/System_Requirements)

I tried to downgrade from wampserver Version 2.5, and to an older. And when I could't open wamp... So please help me... I don't know what to do ;(

Answer (score 0):

The ionCube Loaders were recently updated to support PHP 5 encoded code on PHP 5.5 (starting from version 4.7.2).

I suspect you have an outdated Loader file - try getting the newest Loader from http://www.ioncube.com/loaders.php

Since you already have the Loader installed, this should only be a matter of replacing your ioncube_loader_win_5.5.dll with the newest one. You can verify the upgrade (and confirm that you have indeed an outdated version) by looking at the output of your `phpinfo();`.

Comment: But if i try to download and install the loader, i got this error:

This webpage is not available

Comment: Maybe attaching an errorlog (e.g. via pastie.org or pastebin.com) might be useful. Another possibility is that you might be using 64bit PHP, which is currently still considered experimental on Windows, therefore the ionCube Loaders might not work correctly. Lastly, you may want to contact the ionCube support here: http://ioncu.be/S

Comment: Hmmm, where can i find the log xD

Comment: Logs should be located in your `logs` directory inside the WAMP installation folder, so typically `C:\wamp\logs`. As I mentioned, there might be a possible crash due to PHP 64bit's experimental status - deinstalling your current WAMP and reinstalling 32bit WAMP might be worth a try.